# What is the scaleType I have to use here

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I have an Image of resolution `1600 x 2400`. I want it to be displayed in an ImageView as follow:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

I want the image to:

1. Take full width
2. Maintain Aspect ratio
3. Hence the imageview height must be as per the ratio

**Eg: on a `320 x 600` screen, an image of size `1600 x 2400` must be shown as `320 x 480`**

What I currently get is an **imageview** with dimensions `320 x 2400` with image centered and space on top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

save the image in hdmi folder and use

```
android:src="@drawable/imagename"
```

or you can use

```
android:background="@drawable/imagename"
```

and you can set the heigth and width with 
instead of fill parent or wrap or match use sizes in dp like 100dp or whatever you like.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

example

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
```

1.Please go through the Developers guide first. Supporting Multiple Screens provides a pretty good overview of what you are trying to achieve. It's a challenging task being honest. Most of the iPhone devs enjoy the fixed screen size but we Android devs have to go through this problem. I can recomend few practices that I'm following

2.Try not to use Fixed height and weight as much as you can
Stick to Linear Layout if the layout is not complex. Go to relative layout only when its really mandatory.
Use Wrap and fill parent than giving fixed sizes..
These are the few I can think of.

3.Typically you just provide different layouts and resources for different screen densities and orientations as described in Android documentation

try using

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: This is the image which comes from a server and the resolution varies often.

Comment: if you are trying these then definitely the image will look compressed. isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have calculated how high your view should be: set it's layout parameters through code.

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(320, height));
```